# Single Android Account for multiple apps

Tags: android, accountmanager

in my company, we have two apps that access an authentication (from our own webservice) token from the android account manager. Because this is a SSO, we decided to extract the login (activity and `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`) into a library, that both apps are binding to.
In order to keep the account in the android system, if one of our apps gets uninstalled (assuming the user installed both of our apps), we gave the `accountType` a unified name `ex`. `my.company.auth` (both apps however have the package name `my.company.a` and `my.company.b` respectively).

**The problem lies when both of our apps gets uninstalled: the entry in the account settings in android is still there.**

Does anyone know why or what I am doing wrong? 
Does it have to do with the `accountType`, that has a different 'package name' then the apps?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Did you ever come to solution for this?

Comment: @Jack unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your custom account type component and provide a separate apk file.

When user tries to use any of your app, you need to check if custom account type app exsits on the device or not.

If your account type app doesn't exist, direct user to playstore for downloading your custom account type app so that user can create account for your custom account type and continue to use your app.

In this way, since user created account is not tied to one app and custom account type is separate app, uninstalling any of your app won't delete account created for your custom account type.